# Silverlight add Binding To Controls

Tags: c#, silverlight

```
public class Person

    {

    private int _Id;
    public int Id{get{return value;} set{_Id=value;}}

    private string _Code
    public  string Code{get{return _Code;} set {_Code=value;}}

    private string _Name;
    public string Name{get{return _Name;}set{_Name=value;}}

    }
```

this is my model class

I have a two Combobox in my form.Combo1 and Combo2.
Combo1 DisplayMember Code ValueMember Id
Combo2 DisplayMember Name ValueMember Id

I want to that when I change the Code or Name another combobox edit value and display value change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend several changes:

First, you might want to break your person class out into two classes: Code and Person

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CodeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Code
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CodeText { get; set; }
}
```

Then create a class that you'll set to your view's datacontext, normally called a viewmodel in the MVVM design pattern:

```
public class Data : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public List<Person> People { get; set; }
    public List<Code> Codes { get; set; }

    private Code _selectedCode;
    public Code SelectedCode
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedCode;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedCode = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedCode"));
            SelectedPeople = People.Where(p => p.CodeId == SelectedCode.Id).ToList();
        }
    }

    private List<Person> _selectedPeople;
    public List<Person> SelectedPeople
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedPeople;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedPeople = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedPeople"));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Notice that it implements INotifyPropertyChanged. This is crucial with binding in Silverlight. In the constructor of your MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
Data data = new Data
    {
        Codes = new List<Code>(),// populate your codes

        People = new List<Person>() // populate your people, giving them correct codeids
    }

this.DataContext = data;
```

Now in your view's XAMl:

```
<ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" ItemsSource="{Binding Codes}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCode, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="CodeText" />
<ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,54,0,0" Name="comboBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedPeople}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```

Notice the first combobox binds to the Codes collection on the DataContext. The selectedItem property **TWO-WAY** binds to the SelectedCode property on the datacontext. When the user changes that selected item, the setter on the datacontext gets called. We updated the list of peopel to show, and raise the PropertyChanged event which notifies the view that it needs to update the people box.

Of course, this would be much cleaner if you properly implemented the MVVM design pattern. I like to use the MVVM Light toolkit for this.

I know that was long-winded, but I wanted to guide you down a correct path so you could use this knowledge on this project and in the future :)

Comment: thanks for your answer but if i want to make this from DAtaContext
Adonet Entity Data Model
When i give to Item Source to combobox what do i give for DataBinding

Comment: I would strongly recommend you do some research into the MVVM design pattern. Essentially you have a View Model that you bind the view (XAML) to. In this view model, you'll have collections that UI elements will bind to. In your viewmodel, you'll populate these collections with whatever comes from  the Entity Framework. Check it out, it'll make your coding cleaner and easier: http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/silverlight-4-videos/mvvm-introduction/